# query askubuntu.com through dashboad[unity]

Tags: discussion, search

Is it possible to quesry askubuntu.com for any query/question/issue through unity search . Is there any plugin or a specific setting on the local box ?
Primarily I don't want to open browser for each query I have.

thanks in advance

Comment: Check [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/31712/how-do-i-install-the-ask-ubuntu-unity-lens-and-how-do-i-use-it). It's about installing and using the Ask Ubuntu lens which does what you want.

Answer (score 3):

There is a program that does just that: AskUbuntu Lens. You can get it from the Ubuntu Software Center, or through the instructions on the [program's Launchpad site](https://launchpad.net/askubuntu-lens).

Comment: i installed the utility from the software center, but I am not able to view it under the installed programs in unity . How can I proceed with searching a question on askubuntu lens utility

Comment: I can't get Shutter to run a capture of it, but the "Ask" logo will appear in the bottom of the Dash Lens icon row (along with Documents, Programs, etc.)

Comment: nopes i am not seeing any of the ask icon ..

Comment: Did the Ask item show up in the Dash Lens? I know it took a while for it to show up in mine for some reason.

Comment: nopes even after i restarted my machine, will try installing the plugin once more and will update on this thread

Comment: I did tried but was not able to see the ask item in the Dash lens, BTW my ubuntu version is 12.04

Comment: I am pretty sure the AU lens needs a bit of maintenance and might not work ootb.

Comment: @JorgeCastro Seems so. It will locate tags and such but not actual questions, and I can't find the option in Privacy settings to allow online searches (which supposedly will fix that) from the Dash under 12.04...